# Storing Date Range in MySQL Solution

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on script which requires giving the admin the ability to insert dates for when he wants a parking lot available, the admin inserts dates in a range.

I am having a hard time coming to a solution to what would be the best way to store the dates in MySQL.

Should i store the dates using two columns `AVAILABLE_FROM_DATE` and `AVAILABLE_UNTIL_DATE`?

```
PLID    AVAILABLE_FROM DATE         AVAILABLE_UNTIL_DATE
1       2012-04-01                  2012-04-03
1       2012-04-05                  2012-04-15
2       2012-04-21                  2012-04-30
```

OR should i just use a single column `AVAILABLE_DATE` and store the ranges the admin selects in a new row for each date between the range?

[EDIT START]
What i mean above by using a single column is not to join or split the dates into a single column, i actually mean to store a date in a single row with a single column like below:

```
PLID    AVAILABLE_DATE
1       2012-04-01
1       2012-04-02
1       2012-04-03
```

and so on for all the available dates i want to store.
[EDIT END]

Basically, the admin will want to insert a date range the parking lot is available and allow members to choose that slot if the user is looking for a slot within that range.

OR is there some better and simpler way to do this?

I am currently trying to use the first method using separate columns for the range, but having trouble getting the desired results when looking for parking lots within a range.

[EDIT START]

```
SELECT * FROM `parking_lot_dates`
WHERE (available_from_date BETWEEN '2012-04-22' AND '2012-04-30'
AND (available_until_date BETWEEN '2012-04-22' AND '2012-04-30'))
```

I use the following query on the above rows i have, and it returns empty.
I want it to return the last row having the PLID **2**.
[EDIT END]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just wanting to post that, the reason i haven't accepted any answers yet is that my question has only been half resolved, my main question is still not answered. The main question being which way should i go with for storing the date. `Should i store each date in a separate row or storing a 2 column row with range? or if there is an even simpler method then the ones i just stated?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding your EDIT with the query, you have the logic inside out.  You need to compare whether each date you are checking is inside the range `BETWEEN available_from_date and available_until_date`, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `parking_lot_dates`
WHERE
(
        '2012-04-22' BETWEEN available_from_date AND available_until_date
    AND '2012-04-30' BETWEEN available_from_date AND available_until_date
)
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/911a3/2

**Edit**: Although if you'll want to allow partial-range matches, you'll need both types of logic, i.e., the parking lot is available 4-22 to 4-27, and you need it 4-23 to 4-28.  You can use it for the dates 4-23 to 4-27, but not 4-28.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that, i'm kind of stressed atm. I hate dealing with DATE and TIME, not just in MYSQL though :) The updated version you gave sure does give me the desired result i was looking for :)

Comment: i really wanted to double +1 for posting the link to that sqlfiddle site, its awesome. But unfortunately i can't do it :( so thanking here :)

Comment: I was reading your edit and was alittle confused about what you meant? Do you mean the above logic would work if i had a row with the range 4-22 to 4-27 it would work if i try getting that range but not work if i wanted 4-23 to 4-28? if thats the case then i actually do want it to behave like that i mean i only want it to find a 4-23 to 4-28 range if a row with that range is available in the table.

Answer (score 3):

Why to complicate so much?

```
SELECT *
FROM `parking_lot_dates`
WHERE available_from_date <= '2012-04-22'
AND available_until_date >= '2012-04-30';
```

Comment: @Zubair1 conditions where wrong i fixed that, and why this doesn't work?

Comment: i don't see any thing changed but i still tried it out again and it doesn't give me any results. Probably because this is checking if available_from_date is equal to or more than `2012-04-22` that date isn't a valid row in my list of records that i posted in my question.

Comment: @Zubair1 right and that was changed to oposite conditions from should be <= and until should => as its on site right now

Comment: I'm copy/pasting your code and its not returning anything (MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)).

Comment: I thought you meant you made the changes you were referring to :) but when i made the change `available_from_date <= '2012-04-22'` and `available_until_date >= '2012-04-30'`, its showing the result i want. Thanks. I will try your and mellamokb methods with some more results, though both look solid to me now :)

Answer (score 1):

I personally have found it better to have 2 columns, a start and end time, for searching a specific date, or just looking at it seems easier to me

Comment: Yeah, me too. I am having a tough time deciding here since it looked the two columns approach would complicate things alot in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Using 1 column to store those dates is a bad design from a database point of view (not normalized). It's better to have 2 columns because the results can be retrieved easier and extracting the information from a single column would mean having to do some sort of split. It's just not elegant and it doesn't behave well when requirements change.

Comment: Could you please care to elaborate alittle more? why would i want to split from the single column approach? what i had in mind was that i would simply be looping through the rows to match if the desired range is available?

Comment: @Zubair1 Well, storing both the from date and the until date in one column (which is what you were asking if you should do) can only be done if you somehow store them as character strings with a separator of some sort. For example: `2012-04-03;2012-04-09`. In this case the `;` is the separator and when you get this sequence from the table you would have to split it in 2. Like I was saying: this is a bad design. It would work, but it's a bad practice.

Comment: oh sorry, it seems i was alittle confusing above. But i wasn't going to store the values like you mentioned. I was going to store a date in one row each. Like: **Row 1** `AVAILABLE_DATE = '2012-04-03'` and then **ROW 2** `AVAILABLE_DATE = '2012-04-04'` and **ROW 3** `AVAILABLE_DATE = '2012-04-05'` and so on.. But i agree with what you're saying is a bad design and not normalized, i surely never did meant to do it that way. If i use this method (storing a new row for each date, i would have alot of rows in the table in no time, thats what was really bothering me with this method).